# Auto hide Search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When clicked on right top corner input box a white box appears for search location.. my problem is after searching location everything works well but white box does not close automatically... 
the code is [HERE](https://bellymelly.com/in.html)

```js
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myText").disabled = true;
    }
    
    if ( $(window).width() >= 739) {      
      function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "500px";
      document.getElementById("overlay-layer").style.opacity = "1";
      document.getElementById("overlay-layer").style.display = "block";
      }
    
    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("overlay-layer").style.opacity = "0";
      document.getElementById("overlay-layer").style.display = "none";
    }
    
    function closeBox(){
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("overlay-layer").style.opacity = "0";
      document.getElementById("overlay-layer").style.display = "none";
    }
    } 
    
    
    
    else {
     function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";
      document.getElementById("overlay-layer").style.opacity = "1";
      document.getElementById("overlay-layer").style.display = "block";
      }
    
    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("overlay-layer").style.opacity = "0";
      document.getElementById("overlay-layer").style.display = "none";
    }
    
    function closeBox(){
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("overlay-layer").style.opacity = "0";
      document.getElementById("overlay-layer").style.display = "none";
    }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" onblur="closebox()">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <input type="text" id="myText" name="myText" placeholder="Street Address, city, state" class="search-box"
                   autocomplete="off" onchange="javascript:SearchLocations();">
            <span class="get-location" onclick="getLocation(); return false">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/define-location.png">
                <!--<i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i>-->
                <div>Get Current Location <strong>Using GPS</strong></div>
            </span>
        </span>
```

this is the script i Have used for white box to open and close.. I have added the html js n css that i have used..

Comment: why close automatic.. you must click X icon for close white box

Comment: when we search location and location gets searched the white should get closed automatically

Comment: you asked about after submit right?

Comment: yes. when submitted

Comment: ok pls share code.. i will check and fix tat

Comment: once the search is finished then call the method `closeBox()`

Comment: @Ranjithv https://bellymelly.com/in.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event trigger (onblur or onchange) and hide the element upon triggering

Something along the lines of

```
<ELEMENT id="mySidenav" onblur="closebox()">...</ELEMENT>
```

I'd be able to assist further and improve my answer if I had the mySidenav element, it's css and the effective java script to see what it's current behavior is on your site.

Comment: when added on blur even: when clicked on inner text box we get a google suggestions for address so when that suggestion appears the box gets closed :(

Comment: @MsDesigner I visited the site and it looks good - I've tested it on FF/W10 and Chrome/Android9 and after the desired drop down choice is chosen on tap, enter and click the selection menu closes and brings you back to the parent.

Comment: Yes got conclusion for it yesterday

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event when you press Enter wich call the closing sideNav

Comment: but in mobile we don't press enter we just select address